# Creating a Function which converts a Integer into a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, type-conversion, integer

I'm currently struggling immensely with my python module and I need to "define" a function that converts an integer to a string. I'm really confused about programming in general and was wondering if anyone could help provide an analysis and description on how I would solve this problem / where I'm going wrong with my approach. I know the code is simple but i'm lost on where to even start.

```
x=12

def Converter():
    str(x)
    print (x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Converter(x):
    return str(x)

x = 12
result = Converter(x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: 1. You should pass the parameter to function.
2. You should print the result.

```
x = 12

def Converter(int_number):
    return str(int_number)

print(Converter(x))
```